# Where did Cicero go?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I let Cicero live and left the Dawnstar Sanctuary, I then came back and he was gone! So where is he now? Because I want to make him my follower/companion.

Answer (score 0):

He wont return to the Dawnstar Sanctuary until you finish the quest "Hail Sithis!" After you finish that quest he'll be around the door just outside of the Sanctuary.

[Reference](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Cicero)